# How to render three js geometry on forge model properly

Tags: reactjs, three.js, autodesk-forge

So i am rendering a cylinder geometry which position is updating constantly on the model but once the cylinder geometry  render at position of model and render again at that same position the geometry does not show properly i have tried using "window.viewer.impl.scene.remove(cylinder);","window.viewer.impl.sceneUpdated"(true);
this works but my whole model is updating again and again[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrGjl.png)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { fetchEventSource } from "@microsoft/fetch-event-source";
import { element } from "prop-types";
import { json } from "react-router-dom";

const serverBaseURL = "http://127.0.0.1:2204/video_feed";
const overlayScene = "Twin_Overlay";

function addCylinder(positionsList) {
  if (window.viewer) {
    if (window.viewer.overlays.hasScene(overlayScene)) {
      window.viewer.overlays.removeScene(overlayScene);
    }

    window.viewer.overlays.addScene(overlayScene);
  }
  if (window.THREE) {
    for (let index = 0; index < positionsList.length; index++) {
      let position = positionsList[index];
      let geometry = new window.THREE.CylinderGeometry(0.5, 0.5, 4, 8);
      let material = new window.THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 });
      let cylinder = new window.THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
      cylinder.rotateX(Math.PI / 2);
      cylinder.position.set(position[0] / 1000, position[1] / 1000, 0);
      window.viewer?.overlays.addMesh(cylinder, overlayScene);

       window.viewer.impl.scene.remove(cylinder);
       window.viewer.impl.sceneUpdated(true);
    }
  }
}

async function getData() {
  let runTest = true;
  if (!runTest) {
    const response = await fetch("");
    // const reader = response.body.getReader();
    const positionsList = await response.json();
    // let done, value;
    // while (!done) {
    //   ({ value, done } = await reader.read());
    //   if (done) {
    //     return;
    //   }

    //   let positionsList = new TextDecoder().decode(value);
    //   positionsList = JSON.parse(positionsList);
    addCylinder(positionsList);

    console.log(positionsList);
    // }
  } else {
    setInterval(() => {
      let positionsList = test_getRandomPositions();
      addCylinder(positionsList);
    }, 1000);
  }
}

function test_getRandomPositions() {
  let range = [
    [-35000, 30000],
    [-7000, 16000],
  ];
  let positionsList = [];
  let people_count = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
  for (let i = 0; i < people_count; i++) {
    positionsList.push([
      range[0][0] + Math.random() * (range[0][1] - range[0][0]),
      range[1][0] + Math.random() * (range[1][1] - range[1][0]),
    ]);
  }
  // return [[-4967, -2272]]
  return positionsList;
}

export default getData;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you see is due to the Viewer using Progressive Rendering. If you keep updating the cylinder, it simply defeats the goal of using Progressive Rendering, and you should probably turn it off using:

```
viewer.setProgressiveRendering(bool)
```

However, that will impact large models and make them unresponsive. You could also try to play with the FPS rate using:

```
viewer.impl.setFPSTargets(1, 5, 15) //min, target, max
```

But in the end, if your goal is to make animation, the Viewer isn't the technology you want to use. It might be better to export to glTF and use native ThreeJS canvas for this.

Answer (score 0):

The `viewer.impl.sceneUpdated(true);` is used to update the viewer scenes for native viewer model formats (saying SVF/SVF2), not for overlays. Its equivalent is `viewer.impl.invalidate(true, false, false)`.

If you just want to update the overlay scenes only, call `viewer.impl.invalidate(false, false, true)` instead.